# What comes after tertiary?

Tags: word-request

There's "**primary**", "**secondary**", "**tertiary**". What comes next (at "number 4")?

Sorry, I am not able to phrase this question any better, I hope it is clear from the context what I mean.

Comment: Wouldn't it be fit question for EL&U?

Comment: Do you still have the link? I think that aspect is of interest for English speakers in general, not only to those who learn it.

Comment: I always thought it was "everyone else", "etc" or, in the words of my boss "that other stuff that we'll never actually get to."

Comment: @ChrisLively Well, yeah, it is so a lot of times. I hit upon the need for this word due to ... computer memory. You see: RAM is primary memory, hard disk is secondary memory, optical disks, USB stick, etc. is tertiary memory. Most textbooks stop at this point, but I began wondering what should cloud storage be called? It seems wrong to club it together with tertiary memory for obvious reasons, so I needed something at "no. 4".

Comment: Post-Tertiary ? Will that convey the case of a Hospital whihc is past Tertiary Care?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=There%27s+primary%2C+secondary%2C+tertiary.+What+comes+next

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The sequence may go on like...

> primary, secondary, tertiary, quaternary, quinary, senary, septenary, octonary, nonary, and denary.

I'm not sure after *tertiary*, those words are commonly used though.

Source [here](http://www.english-for-students.com/Primary-1.html)

Comment: Thanks. I have heard those words before, but I thought they are only used for number systems (Unary, binary, ternary, quaternary, ...). Since the first three words in the "sequence" did not match, I thought there might be a different "sequence" for this! :)

Comment: and 8-based number system I would call octal, not octonary. Compare to decimal instead of denary. So Maulik's names are not used for number systems, unless I am completely misinformed.

Comment: You are not misinformed, but you did misinterpret my comment, or rather, I did not express it properly. What I had meant was, I did *guess* quaternary, but then asked this question because it was already "taken" by the number systems sequence. Uhm, something like that, but question is answered now so no problems. :)

Comment: Secondary is 'second to use', 'second in row' etc., while 'binary' is 'system based on 2', so the Happy's sequence is something distinct.

Comment: "Quaternary" is used in geology to describe a certain rock layer. See, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternary. I can't think of an example of any beyond quaternary being used.

Comment: We use quaternary in Chemistry all the time. Quaternary ammonium ion, for example. It is one higher than the tertiary ion.

Comment: Only primary and secondary are used frequently in common speech. Tertiary might be used occasionally, quaternary only in certain subjects, terms beyond that, never.